# How do I concatenate cells and add extra text?

Tags: openoffice-calc

I'm very new to Calc but a relative veteran with Excel. Unfortunately I don't have the latter available to me. I'm attempting to create a new cell inline with the data I need to use like the below

```
AF    Afghanistan
AL    Albania
DZ    Algeria
```

with an output in Column C like this

```
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
```

I've tried to use the `CONCATENATE` function to no avail. Could someone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this in OpenOffice Calc (Version 3).

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I suppose it's a problem of escaping the quotes, since they delimit the "extra strings", too. Anyway, it should work with CONCATENATE, using this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("<option value=""";A1;""">";B1;"</option>")
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, every time messing up argument separators (with german l11n, semicolons instead of commata are used...) With an english (US) localisation, you need this version:

```
=CONCATENATE("<option value=""",A1,""">",B1,"</option>")
```

If doubling the qoutes around the first cell reference doesn't work, try to replace it with `CHAR(34)` (the *decimal* ASCII code for double quotes is 34, while 22 would be the *hex* value):

```
=CONCATENATE("<option value=",CHAR(34),A1,CHAR(34),">",B1,"</option>")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is the exact formula I tried first. unfortunately the `"` acts literally. I couldn't find a method to escape the character, so tried to use `CHAR(22)` based on my local character set that also... did not work. Other than swapping the `"` for `'` im still at a loss on this one.

Comment: thank you! The double quote enclosed by double quotes didnt work but changed the charset to use ASCII and CHAR(34) worked.

Comment: Thanks! The `CHAR(34)` did the trick. The repeated quotes (tried 3, 4, 5 of them) worked only until I closed and re-opened the file - then the quotes had turned into a `0`.

Answer (score 5):

suppose 'AF' was in column A1 and 'Afghanistan' was in column C1, then this would produce the desired result

```
    ="<option value='"&A1&"'>"&C1&"</option>"
```

That code would give you this output

```
    <option value='AF'>Afghanistan</option>
```

Comment: This answer works also great with gnumeric (couldn't make the other answer working).